# Redirect panics to a specified buffer

Tags: rust, panic

Is there any way to do this? In a terminal graphics library, if an exception occurs, the exception will be flushed away before being displayed, making programming very hard to debug using this library.

```
impl Drop for Terminal {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.outbuffer.write_all(&self.driver.get(DevFn::ShowCursor)).unwrap();
        self.outbuffer.write_all(&self.driver.get(DevFn::Reset)).unwrap();
        self.outbuffer.write_all(&self.driver.get(DevFn::Clear)).unwrap();
        self.outbuffer.write_all(&self.driver.get(DevFn::ExitCa)).unwrap();
        self.flush().unwrap(); // If an exception occurs, this will reclear the screen and remove the output
        self.termctl.reset().unwrap();
        SIGWINCH_STATUS.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
        RUSTTY_STATUS.store(false, Ordering::SeqCst);
    }
}
```

If I were to comment out `self.flush().unwrap();` the exception would print, however the terminal would not correctly flush the screen and leave graphics present on the terminal even after the program has ended.

Is it possible to, at the beginning of the program, specify a custom buffer panic will use for writing to? Or possibly write a hacky trick to do this? That way, after the flush we can check to see if anything is inside this buffer, if so we know an exception occurred and can print it out.

---

Running a program that purposely crashes with an arithmetic overflow, currently the output is only 
[image]

By commenting out `self.flush().unwrap();` however, we're greeted with the actual exception, but a very ugly terminal now. This solution will not work as program that execute correctly still need to be flushed since no error is needed to be displayed

[image]

Comment: I doubt that there is a good way to do this, but maybe this function would be useful: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rt/unwind/fn.panicking.html

Comment: @Adrian it's unstable thought ;(. Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: This one isn't unstable: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.panicking.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Panics messages are currently written to stderr so the hacky way to do this is to redirect stderr to a file (`cargo run 2>/path/to/panic.log`).

Alternatively, you can do this in your program itself by using [gag](https://crates.io/crates/gag) (disclaimer, I wrote this library). Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Windows.

The following will redirect stderr until `stderr_redirect` is dropped:

```
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use gag::Redirect;

let log = OpenOptions::new()
    .truncate(true)
    .read(true)
    .create(true)
    .write(true)
    .open("/path/to/panic.log")
    .unwrap();

let stderr_redirect = Redirect::stderr(log).unwrap();
// Your code here...
```

You can also buffer stderr in a temporary file by doing:

```
use gag::BufferRedirect;

let mut stderr_buffer = BufferRedirect::stderr().unwrap();
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Awesome library to help abstract the headache of stderr redirection away

Answer (score 6):

You need to register a *panic hook* with [`std::panic::set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) that captures the output. You can then catch the panic with [`std::panic::catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html):

```
use std::{
    panic,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

fn main() {
    let global_buffer = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));

    let old_hook = panic::take_hook();
    panic::set_hook({
        let global_buffer = global_buffer.clone();
        Box::new(move |info| {
            let mut global_buffer = global_buffer.lock().unwrap();

            if let Some(s) = info.payload().downcast_ref::<&str>() {
                global_buffer.push_str(s);
            }
        })
    });

    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("test panic");
    });

    panic::set_hook(old_hook);

    match result {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("caught panic!");
            println!("I captured:\n\n{}", global_buffer.lock().unwrap())
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Suppress panic output in Rust when using panic::catch_unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35559267/155423)