# Suppress panic output in Rust when using panic::catch_unwind

Tags: exception, rust

I'm using [`panic::catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) to catch a panic:

```
use std::panic;

fn main() {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("test panic");
    });

    match result {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(_) => println!("caught panic!"),
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d92d346014ce523136554fe607cfb53d&version=stable))

This seems to work just fine, but I am still getting the output of the panic to stdout. I'd like this to only print out:

```
caught panic!
```

Instead of

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'test panic', <anon>:6
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
caught panic!
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to register a *panic hook* with [`std::panic::set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) that does nothing. You can then catch it with [`std::panic::catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html):

```
use std::panic;

fn main() {
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_info| {
        // do nothing
    }));

    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("test panic");
    });

    match result {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(_) => println!("caught panic!"),
    }
}
```

As [Matthieu M. notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559267/suppress-panic-output-in-rust-when-using-panicrecover#comment58830945_35559417), you can get the current hook with [`std::panic::take_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.take_hook.html) in order to restore it afterwards, if you need to.

See also:

- [Redirect panics to a specified buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33151317/155423)

Comment: Note: one can use `take_handler` first to be able to restore the original handler after recovery.

Comment: You generally want to install a panic handler once in the beginning of main, before starting any threads and never uninstall it. Instead the panic handler should look at a thread-local variable to decide if it should call the next handler in the chain or if it should swallow the panic silently.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Hi, I wonder whether it is thread safe? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69593235/how-to-get-panic-information-especially-stack-trace-with-rusts-catch-unwind?noredirect=1#comment123009419_69593235 Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use following `catch_unwind_silent` instead of regular `catch_unwind` to achieve silence for expected exceptions:

```
use std::panic;

fn catch_unwind_silent<F: FnOnce() -> R + panic::UnwindSafe, R>(f: F) -> std::thread::Result<R> {
    let prev_hook = panic::take_hook();
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {}));
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(f);
    panic::set_hook(prev_hook);
    result
}
```

Comment: But how can one read the panic message from the result? I checked all its fields but could not find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::panic::set_hook` to suppress the output. Note however that the hook is process-global and it will suppress reporting on *all* panics that may occur within the program.

As already [plugged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47559613/2217151) in my answer to a similar question, I've written a crate that provides a way to suppress the hook with composable filters, including one that works on a per-thread basis.