# How can I silently catch panics in QuickCheck tests?

Tags: testing, rust, panic

In the tests of my [overflower_support](https://crates.io/crates/overflower_support) crate, I have found that I get a lot of spurious reports of panics which are already handled using `std::panic::catch_unwind(_)`. This is a bit unfortunate, as it obscures the real errors that may happen. The messages look like:

```
thread 'safe' panicked at 'arithmetic overflow', src/lib.rs:56
```

To quell those distracting messages, I introduced the `dont_panic(..)` function, which hijacks the panic handler, calls a closure and resets the panic handler when done, returning the closures result. It looks like this:

```
fn dont_panic<F, A, R>(args: A, f: F) -> R
    where F: Fn(A) -> R
{
    let p = panic::take_hook();
    panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| ()));
    let result = f(args);
    panic::set_hook(p);
    result
}
```

However, using this function within the function to check somewhat surprisingly not only quells the desired messages, but also quickcheck's error output, which is obviously valuable to me. This occurs even when limiting tests to one thread.

```
#[test]
fn test_some_panic() {
    fn check(x: usize) -> bool {
        let expected = if x < 256 { Some(x) } else { None };
        let actual = dont_panic(|| panic::catch_unwind(|| { assert!(x < 256); x }).ok());
        expected == actual
    }
    quickcheck(check as fn(usize) -> bool);
}
```

How can I hide the caught panics from my code while keeping QuickCheck's panics visible?

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example of code? If you're wrapping `quickcheck::quickcheck` in `dont_panic`, then it makes sense that your handler is squashing the error messages since the contract of `quickcheck` is to panic on failure. Perhaps you might get more mileage out of `QuickCheck.quicktest`, which returns a `Result` instead of panicing.

Comment: I'm wrapping the `panic::catch_unwind(_)` call in `dont_panic(..)` within the `fn check((usize, usize)) -> bool` function to be checked by `quickcheck::quickcheck`

Comment: Added a mostly complete example (should run once you `use std::panic;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems with my approach:

1. The tests run in parallel (and quickcheck appears to add some parallelism of 
   its own, as `-j 1` appears ineffective to quell the panic messages).
2. The message gets written (or otherwise suppressed by `set_hook(_)`) no
   matter if there's a `catch_unwind(_)` or not.

However, dpc.pw's idea to distinguish based on files in the panic handler was
spot-on. I changed my approach to call an `install_handler()` function before
calling `quickcheck(_)`, which I reproduce here in full:

```
use std::panic;
use std::sync::{Once, ONCE_INIT};

static HANDLER : Once = ONCE_INIT;

fn install_handler() {
    HANDLER.call_once(|| {
        let p = panic::take_hook();
        panic::set_hook(Box::new(move|info| {
            if info.location().map_or(false, |l| l.file() != "src/lib.rs" &&
                    !l.file().ends_with("/num/mod.rs")) {
                p(info);
            }
        }));
    })
}
```

This will quell the panic messages if the panic came from `src/lib.rs` (which
is my `overflower_support` code) or somewhere from `/num/mod.rs` (because the
Rust `libcore` code may panic, too).

Note that you could omit the `Once`, but this would add the handler multiple
times and increase the size of stack traces considerably while exacerbating
test performance.

Answer (score 2):

The default panic handler is printing panic information unconditionally on stderr.

You want to [register your own handler](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html).

Comment: That's what I do in `dont_panic(_)`. However, this unfortunately appears to hide panic information even after it should have been taken.

Comment: Oh. Well, unless you have a way to use eg. a thread local flag, or `PanicInfo`passed to your panic handler to somehow tell one from the other, I don't think there's any other way.

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same problem and a few others, and I ended up writing a crate to solve them:

[panic-control](https://crates.io/crates/panic-control)

With it, your example might be solved by running in a "quiet" thread (assuming you weren't interested in using `catch_unwind` specifically):

```
use panic_control::spawn_quiet;

#[test]
fn test_some_panic() {
    fn check(x: usize) -> bool {
        let expected = if x < 256 { Some(x) } else { None };
        let h = spawn_quiet(|| { assert!(x < 256); x });
        let actual = h.join().ok();
        expected == actual
    }
    quickcheck(check as fn(usize) -> bool);
}
```